# How can I test if I've added baking soda to my cake batter?

Tags: cake, baking-soda

I have prepared some cake mix and while I know I added baking powder, I don't remember whether I have added baking soda in it! Is there anyway to check this (of course without baking the mix ;-). )

This is wheat-based eggless cake. The mix contains wheat, all-purpose flour, sugar and baking powder.

Comment: @Smita The fact that there's already baking powder in there is pretty relevant, so I edited it into the question. The most obvious things would involve somehow seeing if there's any effects from that leavening, but you wouldn't be able to easily tell the difference between having both baking soda and baking powder, and having only baking powder.

Comment: How much baking soda? If it's 3/4 teaspoon (10g) or less, I'd just risk adding it again to be sure it's in there. -Shouldn't hurt the cake too badly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way without a chemlab.  Even cooking a sample wouldn't work because of the baking soda.

Comment: If there *wasn't* baking powder in there, you could pull a little bit out and add some vinegar to see if it would bubble.  But it's a liquid, so the baking powder would bubble, not just the baking soda.

Comment: Oh .. and a trick my mother taught me : pull out all of the ingredients, then put them away as you add them.  If there's anything left on the counter, you forgot to add it.